# Is it possible to restore a virtualBox with same files?

Tags: virtualbox

So I have a macBook Pro 13-Inch 8 GB RAM 500 GB hard drive with an intel i5 processor at 2.5GHz.  I am trying work with Windows 8.1 on a Oracle virtual machine.  I have already installed it but since the first install I now try to start it up and I get this message: "creating process for virtual machine (GUI/Qt)...(1/2)" with a progress bar. I deleted the machine but kept the files.  Is it possible to restore this machine?

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't deleted the files manually or are untouched by VirtualBox when you deleted the virtual machine, then yes, you can restore the machine. All you have to do is open VirtualBox, Click on **Machine -> Add**. A window should appear to choose `.xml` or `.vbox` file. Browse to the location where your virtual machine files are kept and **choose the .vbox** extension file from there. It will restore the machine.

**Note**: My experience is based on VirtualBox for Linux/Windows. But since the program is cross-platform, I assume the options would remain the same.